# Jenkins: Decrypting all passwords in credentials.xml (via Jenkins execution console)

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-groovy

How to decrypt all credentials in the Jenkins credentials.xml using the Jenkins console, in bulk?

I can do this one secret at a time using this snippet of groovy:

```
node {
    def creds

    stage('Sandbox') {
        withCredentials([string(credentialsId: 'VAC_USER',variable: 'C_PASS')]) {
            creds = "\nUser: ${C_USER}\nPassword: ${C_PASS}\n"
        }

        println creds
    }
}
```

However, my knowledge of Groovy is 0, and it's not clear how to print out the entire credentials file, decrypted so that each decrypted password is shown next to it's id.

Answer (score 3):

Simple onliner to dump all system credentials:

`com.cloudbees.plugins.credentials.SystemCredentialsProvider.getInstance().getCredentials().forEach{println it.dump().replace(' ', '\n')}`

Answer (score 1):

The solution in my case was to run groovy extraction code via the Jenkins terminal (assuming one has administrator access).

The code below extracts the bulk of credentials configured in Jenkins (username+passwords, ssh-keys, secret texts) and can be extended to other kinds of secrets in the credentials store:

```
def creds = com.cloudbees.plugins.credentials.CredentialsProvider.lookupCredentials(
    com.cloudbees.plugins.credentials.common.StandardUsernameCredentials.class,
    Jenkins.instance,
    null,
    null
);

//SSH-Secrets

for (c in creds) {
     println( ( c.properties.privateKeySource ? "ID: " + c.id + ", UserName: " + c.username + ", Private Key: " + c.getPrivateKey() : ""))
}

//Username+Password Combination

for (c in creds) {
     println( ( c.properties.password ? "ID: " + c.id + ", UserName: " + c.username + ", Password: " + c.password : ""))
}

//Secret Text
def creds2 = com.cloudbees.plugins.credentials.CredentialsProvider.lookupCredentials(
    com.cloudbees.plugins.credentials.common.StandardCredentials.class,
    Jenkins.instance,
    null,
    null
);

//Secret Strings
for (c in creds2) {
     println( ( c.properties.secret ? " ID: " + c.id + " DESCRIPTION: " + c.description +  " SECRET: " + c.secret : ""))
}
```